# Javascript : Get the HTMLAudioElement currently playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, audio

How can I access an `HTMLAudioElement` that is currently playing, without knowing anything about it? It is not an `<audio>` tag  in the page, it is a

```
audio_element = document.createElement('audio');
```

But now (at the time when I want the audio to pause) the DOM has been modified by a

```
$('#details').html('').load(ajax_loader, "id=" + id, function() {
    <!-- another playlist -->
}
```

And I can't seem to retrieve my `audio` element back. **It's no longer in the DOM, but the audio is still playing** witch is fine BTW, but now I want to play something else. And when I do, I can hear both audio files.

So really my question is just that : How can I access an `HTMLAudioElement` that is currently playing, without knowing *anything* about it?

Comment: Could it be as simple as changing to  `$('#details').html('').load(...` ? If not I think you would need to expand you example with more code/an example

Comment: What do you think about document.all? It is a pseudoarray of all elements in the DOM. Then you can pay attention to ```paused``` property of the HTMLAudioElement.

Comment: You are right, my pseudo-code was not "functional", sorry. And no, an example would be too complex to produce, it is not my code, and it spans across multiple files, hence the "theoretical" take of my question : Can I, say, scan the DOM at a given point and *get* the reference of the audio playing, or can I not (witch bewilders me : Where is this audio now ? Has the browser passed it to the OS and really lost all track of it!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't** get access to element **without reference** to it.

So in that case you have two ways:

- insert the audio element inside the DOM `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('audio'))` and make it hidden by css `display: none;` and then you can use get access by `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')`
- save reference to audio element in some scope: `window.audioElement = document.createElement('audio')`

Thanks

Comment: Seems you (and unobf below) are right... I ended up storing the object inside the DOM... So that means that a situation where a) the browser is playing audio, and b) said browser is virtually incapable of knowing it, let alone acting upon it, is **possible**... Is it just me, or is it a security flaw?

Comment: I think that usually security is aimed on content which is loaded from other sites. The inability to get current playing audio is a feature of architecture.

Comment: Remark: the browser does know about the audio element, only the *JavaScript code that executes on the site* can't get the element without a reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you keep a reference to the audio element when you create it, you can still access the audio element via that reference and then clear the reference to have it garbage collected. So a simple example using global variables (not good practice but you can modify this to work in your module) is:

```
window.audio_element = document.createElement('audio');
```

and then later

```
window.audio_element.pause();
window.audio_element = undefined;
```

Here is a reference to the mozilla documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio and the WhatWG specification https://developers.whatwg.org/the-video-element.html#the-video-element

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly that does not answer the question. To test it would mean re-factoring the whole script...
If I keep a reference, then I *know something* about the audio being played.

Comment: But if I replace all the audio.element by window.audio.element, it still works as before, meaning that (after the `load()`)`window.audio.element.pause()` *still does not pause* the audio being played, so apparently this global var is not *that* global..?

Comment: > I think it is the only way to do it...

If you really think that, then I'm sorry but why did you answer at all ? You basically killed the question (I've been stuck on this problem for days now) oh well.

Comment: don't get upset with me because you wrote crappy code that doesn't clean itself up properly

Comment: Take it easy unobf, and thanks for your answer anyway. And yes, I do write crappy code.

Comment: unobf, I feel bad about downvoting your answer, especially since you are right after all. Please edit it in some way (juste add a link to the HTML5 audio ref, something like that) so I can make it right. My problem is solved. I am a happy man anew.